# pandas groupe by on multiple column and select all those column used in group by in new dataframe

Tags: select, pandas-groupby, multiple-columns

```
select count(ErrorCode) as "counterr",DateOnly,System_id,ErrorType,ErrorCode from dbo.error group 
by(DateOnly,System_id,ErrorType,ErrorCode)
```

i have to convert this sql code into pandas and want the output as pandas dataframe having column name as counterr,DateOnly,System_id,ErrorType,ErrorCode

Answer (score 0):

error is my Pandas dataframe

```
errorMaster= 
error.groupby(["System_id","DateOnly","ErrorType","ErrorCode","Acknowledged"]
              )["ErrorCode"].agg(CountErr='count').reset_index()
errorMaster
```

you need to give reset_index() else you will be able to print the column "CountErr" Only rather getting all selected column in your output